# How to get Hama AC-150 webcam to work in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, webcam

When I first plugged it in, Windows recognized it as "HP Basic Starter Camera". The *Camera* app in Windows 10 doesn't recognize it, I'm getting a 
"We can't find your camera" message and a black screen.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Which driver have you installed?

Comment: https://www.hama.com/00086510/hama-ac-150-webcam#downloads this driver form hama site @harrymc

Comment: Why are you trying to install a dedicated driver?

Comment: @gronostaj Wich driver should i install then? This is only driver for this camera.

Comment: It looks like a generic webcam, just plug it in and it should work.

Comment: @gronostaj He find "HP basic started camera" and when i open camera on Windows 10 it says "We can't find you camera" and black screen.

Comment: Your driver is not guaranteed to work in Windows 10, only for Windows 7. You should maybe get another webcam.

Answer (score 2):

Your driver is not guaranteed to work in Windows 10, only for Windows 7.
The advice I can give is:

- If the device functions well with the current driver, or even mostly well, don't change anything
- Otherwise, delete the driver you installed and reboot, to let Windows
  install its own driver.
  This is done in Device Manager, open Imaging devices, right-click
  the camera and choose Uninstall device, and finally reboot.
- If nothing helps, the webcam needs to be replaced by one that is supported
  in Windows 10.

Comment: It says system requirement: windows 10, windows 8, windows 7, vista and xp at technical specs

Comment: The download page of the driver says "WIN 2000/XP/VISTA/WIN 7". If you found "Windows 10" on the technical description of the device, then try using the driver from Windows, as described in my second point.

Comment: Looks like that camera is working on skype and other apps but wont work on Windows camera app with driver from site. Dont know why but if is working great!

Answer (score -2):

Same camera as SeedLink SL-6820. See product page https://www.speedlink.com/Sphere-Webcam-350k-Pixel/SL-6820

No extra drivers needed when you can see "HP Basic Starter Camera". Just download SL-6820 Software https://www.speedlink.com/media/70/2f/dd/1611843898/vp_eye30.zip (133MB), no installation needed, try AVI.EXE or VPEYEV1.EXE!
But nevertheless the MS Camera app might not work with it.